# GoogleMobileAds WebView

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, google-mobile-ads, google-ads-api

Does anyone know why `GoogleMobileAds` still has `UIWebView` in it? I installed the latest version of `GoogleMobileAds` `(7.60.0)` but when I run `grep -r UIWebView Pods/` it detects that `GoogleMobileAds` has `UIWebView`

If I read the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rel-notes) that `GoogleMobileAds` has removed all references to `UIWebView` since version `7.55.0` then why it still appear?

I've tried to reinstall, `pod deintegrate`, `pod update` but it still has `UIWebView`

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't. The grep you're running is picking up `GADOMIDUIWebViewJSExecutor`

```
$ nm GoogleMobileAdsFramework-Current/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds | grep UIWebView
                 U _OBJC_CLASS_$_GADOMIDUIWebViewJSExecutor
GoogleMobileAdsFramework-Current/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADOMIDUIWebViewJSExecutor_756cbedfcadc00b64a868c185cab1ab0.o):
---------------- t -[GADOMIDUIWebViewJSExecutor .cxx_destruct]
---------------- t -[GADOMIDUIWebViewJSExecutor initWithWebView:]
---------------- t -[GADOMIDUIWebViewJSExecutor injectJavaScriptFromString:]
---------------- t -[GADOMIDUIWebViewJSExecutor jsEnvironment]
---------------- t -[GADOMIDUIWebViewJSExecutor supportBackgroundThread]
---------------- D _OBJC_CLASS_$_GADOMIDUIWebViewJSExecutor
---------------- D _OBJC_IVAR_$_GADOMIDUIWebViewJSExecutor._webView
---------------- D _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GADOMIDUIWebViewJSExecutor
```